# How can adding jar to build path affect code even if I don't use any of classes included at it

Tags: java, dicom

I had a situation of adding `.dic` file *(DICOM: Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine Format)* into a swing java application and I had `Dicom.jar` to recognize the `.dic` 
extentions

once I added the `Dicom.jar` to build path the Code ran normally when I removed the jar from the 
build path there weren't any errors in the Code **(I never used any of classes included in `Dicom.jar`)**

But I'm very Confused how could the code recognized the `Dicom.jar` if it doesn't use any of its classes

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding what is going on is "dynamic class loading".  Something in the runtime libraries that your application uses is finding and loading classes from that JAR file.

This is most likely happening because Dicom provides code that conforms to the SPI mechanism used by one of the subsystems of the Java standard libraries that do this kind of thing.  (And there are a few instances of SPIs in the Java libraries.)

Dicom could also be interacting with other 3rd-party code in other ways; e.g. via a 3rd-party SPI or old-fashioned "put the classname into a property file" mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the Dicom uses an approach called SPI (Service Provider Interface). This [link](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3848881/Service-Provider-Interface-Creating-Extensible-Java-Applications.htm) provides a pretty good explanation.

This approach is used for images, but also for [sound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html), and you can create your own SPI when needed.

Comment: +1 - The key to understanding what is going on is "dynamic class loading".